# How to convert a string variable into int and add the two integers at the same time?

Tags: php

This is my code:

```
    <?php
    //for reference
    $intqty = (int) $_POST["qty_input"];
    (int)$_SESSION['cart_qty'] += $intqty;
    ?>
```

The `$_POST['qty']` is a string and I'm trying to add and store the values in a session variable and its not working. The output of when I `echo $_SESSION['cart_qty'];` is 0;

Comment: `var_dump($intqty)`?

Comment: What @u_mulder is asking is _What is in the `$_POST["qty_input"]` value?_

Comment: `(int)$_SESSION['cart_qty']` is a value. It doesn't make any sense to put it in the left side of an assignment operation. Imagine `$_SESSION['cart_qty']` is `21`. The second line of code is the same as `21 += $intqty;`.

Comment: @u_mulder  the output is `int(0) 0`

Comment: Maybe he should initialize the $_SESSION['cart_qty'] to 0 in the start. `$_SESSION['cart_qty'] = 0;`

Comment: `var_dump($_POST["qty_input"])`?

Comment: @axiac So how do you propose I write it?

Comment: @KubiRoazhon Is correct. You cannot `+=` into an uninitialized variable. Well you can but the results are a bit unpredictable

Comment: _Small Note:_ Also I dont see a `session_start()` anywhere in this code. Without that nothing in the SESSION will work

Comment: @RiggsFolly apart from getting a notice, there is no undesired side effect on using an uninitialized variable. It is initialized on the first use with a value appropriate for the operation (`0`, `''`, `array()` etc.). And the result is not unpredictable in PHP. It is, indeed, [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) in C, C++ and other compiled languages, but not in PHP.

Comment: @axiac Are you sure. I am pretty sure this has tripped me up in the past

Comment: @RiggsFolly It is a [documented behaviour](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php): *"It is not necessary to initialize variables in PHP **however it is a very good practice**. Uninitialized variables have a default value of their type depending on the context in which they are used - booleans default to `FALSE`, integers and floats default to zero, strings (e.g. used in echo) are set as an empty string and arrays become to an empty array."*

Comment: @axiac Ok, I cannot reproduce it now of course. So not sure what I was doing that tripped me up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `$_POST["qty_input"]` is not valid number, casting to `int` will return `0`.

```
$_SESSION['cart_qty'] = (int)$_SESSION['cart_qty'] + $intqty;
```

Answer (score 1):

If both your variables are valid numbers, the cast will be implicit if you use them as numbers, for example if you try to add them :

```
$_SESSION['cart_qty'] += $_POST['qty_input'];
```

No more, no less.

If this line doesn't work, then it's weird. It could mean that one or both of the values is/are not valid number(s) but I assume you already checked the content of your variables.

Answer (score 0):

You would need explicitly show the values stored in your `$_POST` and `$_SESSION` with something like a `var_dump` to be sure the value is indeed a string that could be converted to an int (ie "23"), but even so you should not need to cast the string to an int. PHP supports [type juggling](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php) which basically implicitly casts variables to the correct type when performing operations on them.

That should explain how to cast a string to an int, as for how to add two integers at the same time, just use `+` or `+=` depending on where you want the value stored.